# Nested text interpolation in Angular 12: binding a string with nested curly braces

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

I have these variables in my component:

```
name = 'Steven';
greeting = 'Hi, {{name}}!';
```

and in my template:

```
<div [innerHtml]="greeting"></div>
```

This outputs `Hi, {{name}}!` but I want it to render `Hi, Steven!`. How can I do this?

This is a simplified example to show the issue I have. In reality, our current system allows messages with one or more component variables.

I'm using Angular 12.

Comment: You can try something like `greeting = 'Hi, {{name}}'.replace('{{name}}', this.name)`.

Comment: But I don't know what to replace. It could be {{firstName}}, {{name}}, {{nickname}}, ...

Answer (score 2):

In your `ts` file you cannot use Angular template string interpolation.  Instead you should use the JS/TS string interpolation, `${expresssion}` with a JS/TS getter method.

```js
name = 'Steven';

get greeting(): string {
  return `Hi, ${this.name}!`;
} ;
```

And your html

```html
<div [innerHtml]="greeting"></div>
```

This will allow you to build the `greeting` dynamically based on the current value of `name`.  If `name` changes, the `greeting` updates.

See stackblitz link below

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2kq5vb

Answer (score 0):

if you are using property binding then you have to do something like

```
<div [innerHtml]="'Hi, ' + name + '!'"></div>
```

if you remove the property binding then you can do something like this:

```
<div innerHtml="Hi, {{name}}!"></div>
```

Comment: I don't know what `greeting` will be. It's a constant in my example but that's not the case in our scenario. It could be anything, using any component variable.

Comment: but you know what it will contain a syntax '{{ name }}' inside it that you can update with a name property
There must be a pattern that you must know when trying to update the string.

Comment: Not really, it could be anything. The component has a lot of variables and the message is configurable in our backoffice. So it can be `Hi {{name}}` but also `Welcome back {{nickname}}, we haven't seen you since {{lastLogon}}`. I would like Angular to interpolate `greeting` first (in controller code if needed) and than use interpolation in the template to actually show the interpolated `greeting`.

Comment: in that case you need to know the collection of what they are interpreting as what, eg you need a list of what is interpreted as what , then run it though a loop and and use replace.